# How do I embed a Plotly chart in my website so that it displays properly on mobile devices

Tags: python, iframe, plotly, embed

I am trying to embed a Plotly chart created in python into my website. I have posted the chart to Plotly and am embedding it from there. When viewing the chart using a desktop on the website it looks as intended. The problem occurs when loading the chart on a mobile. It appears that the data displayed in the graph properly adjusts in size but the labels and titles do not. This makes the graph appear weirdly compressed. I have included 2 images below. The first is how it displays on desktop and the second is how it displays on mobile.
[Example on Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35fXx.jpg)

[Example on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z42Mb.jpg)

This is the iframe that I have used to embed the graph:

```
<iframe src="//url.embed?link=false&modebar=false" title='Interactive or visual content' class='flourish-embed-iframe' frameborder='0' scrolling='yes' style='width:100%;height:600px;overflow:auto;' sandbox='allow-same-origin allow-forms allow-scripts allow-downloads allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation'></iframe>
```

I have tried adjusting the size within the iframe but have found this has generally made it worse.

Is there anyway I can create the chart so that it properly adjusts when viewing it on mobile?